# Ubuntu 9.04 :: Cannot mount Windows partitions (or hard drives)

Tags: ubuntu, mount

This is a known Ubuntu error in Jaunty. The only thing is that the bug fix was in Geek, not English. Could someone explain the fix to me? Here it is:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/300443 - comment #4

**Update**: Turned out I didn't have the right permissions to mount the other partitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded and compiled the nfts-3g program from it's website.

I also installed pysdm, which I think was the real solution, because it let the normal user (me) mount the windows partitions.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of the solutions posted in that thread date from January, which indicates they refer to the Alpha releases of Jaunty. The simplest solution (which dates from April, around the time Jaunty was officially released) [is this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/300443/comments/40), which reads:

> I had to do `apt-get remove ntfs-config; apt-get install ntfs-config` and `dpkg-reconfigure ntfs-config` before the bug went away.

The removing and reinstalling are probably redundant, so just run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ntfs-config` .